# Can't launch OpenStack Newton Horizon Dashboard IOError:[remote 192.168.245.1:40166] ImportError: cannot import name security_group_rules

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I installed OpenStack newton and Tacker on ubuntu 16.04 by following this 2 links 
https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-ubuntu/

https://docs.openstack.org/developer/tacker/install/manual_installation.html

when I open the GUI I am getting the below error

The last five lines in /var/log/apache2/error.log file

[Sun Jun 04 16:47:19.607996 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 31931:tid 140556571473664] [                                                                                        remote 192.168.245.1:40166]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_das                                                                                        hboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/cinder.py", line 38, in

[Sun Jun 04 16:47:19.608013 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 31931:tid 140556571473664] [                                                                                        remote 192.168.245.1:40166]     from openstack_dashboard.api import nova

[Sun Jun 04 16:47:19.608026 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 31931:tid 140556571473664] [                                                                                        remote 192.168.245.1:40166]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_das                                                                                        hboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/nova.py", line 34, in

[Sun Jun 04 16:47:19.608065 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 31931:tid 140556571473664] [                                                                                        remote 192.168.245.1:40166]     from novaclient.v2 import security_group_rules a                                                                                        s nova_rules

[Sun Jun 04 16:47:19.608104 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 31931:tid 140556571473664] [                                                                                        remote 192.168.245.1:40166] ImportError: cannot import name security_group_rules

Comment: Iam getting this error just after installing tacker

Comment: did you find a solution? I am running into same thing.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, use `find /usr -name "security_group_rules.py"` to check the file isn't exist, usually it may in path `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/v2/`

if the file exist, check the python2.7 package search path, like this

[image]

make sure the file path is in the package search path

secondly, check the path `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`, this path  may have the same dir `novaclient/v2/` and this may the **root cause** which lead to the error, when python search packages, it first check this directory

you can `mv /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient-old`, or just remove the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient` directory

finally, casuse this error is the `apt install` and `pip install` have install the similar packages in different path.